# How can I get the URL for an API if the URL I want is in the API's JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, soundcloud

So i'm using the soundcloud API to grab favorites from users.  Their max limit is 200 per request, however in the end of the object they have an a_href key who's value is the next page of favorites.

Basically, i'm trying to place a button so that a user can click it and it will feed them the next 200 likes.  My issue is getting access to the data.a_href without doing multiple calls to the original API URL.  My code looks something like this:

```
function getAPIURL(username, subSection){
    apiurl = "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/" + username + "/" + subSection + "/?client_id=" + clientID + limit + "&linked_partitioning=1"
} 


function getFavorites(){
    titleList.length = 0;
    artistList.length = 0;
    imgList.length = 0;
    idList.length = 0;
    $(".trackList").html("");
    username = $("input").val();
    subSection = "favorites";
    getAPIURL(username, subSection); 
    getAPI(apiurl);
}

function getAPI(apiurl){
    $.getJSON(apiurl, function(data) {
        //Does some stuff then
        $(".nextPage").on("click", function(){
            titleList.length = 0;
            artistList.length = 0;
            imgList.length = 0;
            idList.length = 0;
            $(".trackList").empty();
            getAPI(data.next_href);
        })
      });
}
```

The above works great when I go to the second page.  However, when I try to go to the third it's like its calling both the second page and the first page as well before calling the third page....

Any ideas?

Comment: Each time you call `getAPI(apiurl)`, you add another onclick to the next page button. What happens if you do `$(".nextPage").off('click').on('click'...`?

Comment: That works!! Can you explain a little why that's working?  I guess I don't fully understand the .on("click").  Still a huge JS noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reapplying the click with every call:

```
function getAPI(apiurl){
    $.getJSON(apiurl, function(data) {
        //Does some stuff then
        $(".nextPage").on("click", function(){
            titleList.length = 0;
            artistList.length = 0;
            imgList.length = 0;
            idList.length = 0;
            $(".trackList").empty();
            getAPI(data.next_href);
        })
      });
}
```

Each time it's called, the number of click handlers goes up by 1 and each will be called.

To stop reapplying it, remove it then apply it. `off()` does the removal.

```
function getAPI(apiurl){
    $.getJSON(apiurl, function(data) {
        //Does some stuff then
        $(".nextPage").off("click").on("click", function(){
            titleList.length = 0;
            artistList.length = 0;
            imgList.length = 0;
            idList.length = 0;
            $(".trackList").empty();
            getAPI(data.next_href);
        })
      });
}
```

To make life easier in the future, separate your `onclick` binding from the `getAPI` call.

If the button isn't present in the DOM until some event happens, bind to a parent element and they'll be no need for `off`/`on`:

```
$("PARENT OF THE .nextPage BUTTON").on("click", ".nextPage", function(){
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this helped a lot! Actually helped me fix quite a few other bugs in the program.  I wonder if you have any suggestion for this question: I need to include a back button as well to get the previous results, however there isn't an a_href key for the previous page value.  Would the best way be to somehow store the next_href key for each page? Unfortunately there isn't a uniform way for me just adjust the page number of the next_href link.  They appear to have a unique key per page....

Comment: You're right, store the previous links in an array and use them as needed.